# Angular 4 undefined, I believe I am missing something fundamental

Tags: angular, typescript

So, I am working on an angular project. I am fetching data with an HTTP call.

To verify that I am doing stuff right, I usually print them out on the console. When I try to print with console.log() my results, it only works with objects inside my methods. When I go out of the scope of the method, console.log() does not work anymore and prints out an array with no values. I think I am understanding closures the wrong way.

Anyway, my real issue is that I fetch data from a JSON file and converts them into two separate arrays, then I am trying to merge those two arrays.

Here is the service that I am using:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http/';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ManagersService {
  list$;
  contacts$: Array<any>;
  items$;
  nameDatabase: { name: string, id: number  }[] = [] ;
  emailDatabase = [];
  managersList;
// tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
private url = ''; 
//I am hidden the URL, because it contains private data,
but it is a complex nested JSON object

  constructor(private http: Http) {


  }

  getList() {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
    .map(response => response.json());
  }


   getManagersNames() {

    this.getList()
    .subscribe(list => {
      this.list$ = list.data;
      //console.log(this.list$);
      for ( const l of this.list$) {
        const managerName = l.attributes.name;
        const managerId = parseInt(l.id);
        const manager = { name: managerName, id: managerId };
        this.nameDatabase.push(manager);
      }



    });
    const x = this.nameDatabase;
    return x;
  }

  checkId() {
    this.getList()
    .subscribe(list => {
      this.contacts$ = list.included;
      console.log(this.contacts$);
      for ( const c of this.contacts$) {
        const managerId = parseInt(c.id) - 1;
        return managerId;
      }
    });
  }

  getManagersContacts() {
    this.getList()
    .subscribe(list => {
      this.contacts$ = list.included;
     // console.log(this.contacts$);
      for ( const c of this.contacts$) {
        if (c.attributes.email) {
          const managerEmail = c.attributes.email;
          const managerId = parseInt(c.id) - 1;
          const manager = { email: managerEmail, id: managerId };
          this.emailDatabase.push(manager);
        } else {
          const managerName = c.attributes.name;
          const managerId = parseInt(c.id);
          const manager = { name: managerName, id: managerId };
          this.nameDatabase.push(manager);
        }
      }

    });
    const y = this.emailDatabase;
    return y;
  }



}
```

Here is the component that I am using:

```
import { ManagersService } from './../services/managers.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-items',
  templateUrl: './list-items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-items.component.css']
})
export class ListItemsComponent implements OnInit {
// tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length



constructor(private service: ManagersService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const x = this.service.getManagersContacts();
    console.log(x);
    const y = this.service.getManagersNames();
    console.log(y);
    const hash = new Map();
    x.concat(y).forEach(function(obj) {
        hash.set(obj.id, Object.assign(hash.get(obj.id) || {}, obj));
    });
    const finalDatabase = Array.from(hash.values());
    console.log(finalDatabase);
    return finalDatabase;

  }

}
```

Finally, my app.module.ts:

```
import { ManagersService } from './services/managers.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ListItemsComponent } from './list-items/list-items.component';
import { SearchListComponent } from './search-list/search-list.component';
import { DropDownComponent } from './drop-down/drop-down.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ListItemsComponent,
    SearchListComponent,
    DropDownComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ManagersService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: what exactly you expect?

Comment: To be able to merge both arrays. When I console.log(finalDatabase); the result of the final array, It returns an empty one. @Vithubati

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! The key fundamental concept that you are missing is that http is asynchronous. That means that you will not be able to console.log out the data immediately after you have called to request it. You have to wait until that data is returned.

Comment: Thank you again DeborahK. !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure about attempting to answer this because without a plunker or stackblitz of the code ... the possibility that I am going to get a typed code example exactly right is small. But hopefully this will give you an idea of what needs to be done.

First, the recommended rule of thumb is to use `subscribe` as close to the UI as possible. That way you have notification of when the data retrieval is complete and can work with that data as needed.

Second, to reformat/transform the data from the Http call to the format desired by the components, use `.map` instead of `.subscribe` in the service.

**Service**

The service would then look something like this:

NOTE: Not syntax checked or verified!

```
  getManagersContacts() {
    this.getList().map(list => {
      this.contacts$ = list.included;
     // console.log(this.contacts$);
      for ( const c of this.contacts$) {
        if (c.attributes.email) {
          const managerEmail = c.attributes.email;
          const managerId = parseInt(c.id) - 1;
          const manager = { email: managerEmail, id: managerId };
          this.emailDatabase.push(manager);
        } else {
          const managerName = c.attributes.name;
          const managerId = parseInt(c.id);
          const manager = { name: managerName, id: managerId };
          this.nameDatabase.push(manager);
        }
      }
    });
    return this.nameDatabase;
  }
```

**Component**

And the component would look something like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const x = this.service.getManagersContacts().subscribe(names => {
                // the data is retrieved at this point, so add any code here
                // inside the subscribe
                console.log(names);
              })
    // your other code
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response that should be helpfull :) !

Comment: @fastblast Her responses are always helpful! Pay attention on it:)

Comment: @yurzui Thank you for the feedback. I will do so.

Comment: @deborahK I did so. But now, I do not have anything on my console.log() I am left with an empty array. While with the subscription, I was able to see the names, emails and IDs on the arrays.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer ... it is really difficult to get the code just right when I don't have a working example. If you need further help, you may need to build a plunker or stackblitz with ONLY the basics that illustrate your issue and we can look into it further.

Comment: If you would like to see a complete working example of this technique, you can find several in my github including this one: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-routing